# modernizr not working with IE9 and lower

Tags: jquery, html, modernizr, pushstate, popstate

When I click links in my site it works in major browsers, but IE9 and lower do not work. I click the links and nothing happens! Console says: "event.returnValue is deprecated. Please use the standard event.preventDefault() instead."

I'm using this method from this website: http://sudojesse.github.io/dynamic-page/index.html

when I use this website in IE9 and lower it works (with refreshing the page, but it works!).
What am I doing wrong?

EDIT: When putting everything in a subfolder it works! Could it be something with htacess?

```
  <script src="http://html5shiv.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script>
```

```
<script type='text/javascript' src='js/modernizr.js'></script>
<script>$(function() {

if(Modernizr.history){

var newHash      = "",
    $mainContent = $("#main-content"),
    $pageWrap    = $("#page-wrap"),
    baseHeight   = 0,
    $el;

$pageWrap.height($pageWrap.height());
baseHeight = $pageWrap.height() - $mainContent.height();

$( "a" ).on("click", function() {
    _link = $(this).attr("href");
    history.pushState(null, null, _link);
    loadContent(_link);
    return false;
});

function loadContent(href){
    $mainContent
            .find("#guts")
            .fadeOut(200, function() {
                $mainContent.hide().load(href + " #guts", function() {
                    $mainContent.fadeIn(200, function() {
                        $pageWrap.animate({
                            height: baseHeight + $mainContent.height() + "px"
                        });
                    });

                });
            });
}

$(window).bind('popstate', function(){
   _link = location.pathname.replace(/^.*[\\\/]/, ''); //get filename only
   loadContent(_link);
});
} // otherwise, history is not supported, so nothing fancy here.
});</script>
```

Comment: The History API isn't supported in IE9 and below, so `Modernizr.history` should return false, and the script is never executed.

Comment: how do I change that? why does it work here: http://sudojesse.github.io/dynamic-page/index.html

Comment: You can't change that, if it doesn't support the API, it doesn't support the API. Why it works on some demo page is beyond me, but it surely isn't the History API working in IE9, it's probably reloading the page, and just faking the animations.

Comment: reloading the page is ok for IE9 and below. I just don't understand why my links do not work on IE9. I don't see what I did differently.

Comment: this isn't an issue with modernizr, so you should change the title to prevent confusion from people who come here later looking to learn from it :]

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
$( "a" ).on("click", function(e) {
    _link = $(this).attr("href");
    history.pushState(null, null, _link);
    loadContent(_link);
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

Comment: put this in there:  `var evt = e || window.event;` and replace the `e.preventDefault()` with `evt.preventDefault()`

Comment: thank you, but that did not help me!  I just found out that a javascript is making IE to not work. not sure ho to handle this now

Answer (score 0):

It now works!
Turns out a script (jquery lavalamp) was blocking it, but only in IE!
The NSA should delete that browser!!